# Fresh blueberries vs dried blueberries in a cookie recipe

Tags: substitutions, fruit

Can fresh blueberries be used instead of dried blueberries for baking cookies? This is for a cookie recipe that calls for 1/2 cup dried blueberries.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not going to work. The fresh blueberries are mostly water, and all that water will definitely be enough to throw off the cookies. Other options:

- use a different kind of dried fruit
- dry the berries yourself, probably more work than you want ([see this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/how-do-i-make-dried-blueberries))
- turn them into [thumbprint cookies](https://www.google.com/search?q=thumbprint%20cookies&tbm=isch), and use blueberry jam (if that works with your recipe)